# Setting and reading a session

Tags: session, asp-classic, session-state

I have a couple of classic ASP pages that require a user to enter their email and a specified 'keycode' that they have been given in order to gain access to a voucher that they can have emailed to them.

A voucher code is then dynamically generated and (currently) sent in the query string of the url to a second page that would then give the user the option to have the voucher emailed.

I now want to change this so that the voucher code is set as a session, rather than passing it via the url. But i'm having trouble trying to set the session.

I have pasted the code here in a Gist on github: http://gist.github.com/187622

The code errors on Line 47 as follows;

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

Object required: 'Session'

/bennettsget/default.asp, line 47

I was wondering if anyone would be able to help? Apologies if my explanation or terminology is not correct. Classic ASP is not my language of choice, but it is one of those sites you inherit when starting a new job.

Thank you.

Comment: I feel your pain.  Been a long time since I had to work with ASP Classic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the word "Set".  Try

```
Session("fullcode") = fullcode
```

Set is usually used in conjunction with a full-blown object.  When you're working with a Session, you're really setting a value for a *collection* rather than the creation of an *object*.

Comment: @bpayne: Thanks so much. Just one word stopped it all working. Heh.